# Scraping NBA Game Logs with Python

Tags: python, pandas, nba-api

I am trying to use the `nba_api` to scrape the 2023 game logs for NBA players. However, I am only getting an empty dataframe. This is unexpected given I am testing my code with Lebron James.

Is there something wrong with my code? Thank you in advance.

```
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import playergamelogs

Test = playergamelogs.PlayerGameLogs(player_id_nullable = 2544, 
                                     season_nullable = 2023).\
                                     get_data_frames()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 entries in 2023 for Lebron James. However, you should use `PlayerGameLog` (singular) instead of `PlayerGameLogs` (plural):

```
import pandas as pd
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import playergamelog
from nba_api.stats.library.parameters import SeasonAll

# Default is current season
Test = playergamelog.PlayerGameLog(player_id=2544, season=SeasonAll.current_season).get_data_frames()[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> Test
  SEASON_ID  Player_ID     Game_ID     GAME_DATE      MATCHUP WL  MIN  FGM  FGA  FG_PCT  FG3M  FG3A  FG3_PCT  FTM  FTA  FT_PCT  OREB  DREB  REB  AST  STL  BLK  TOV  PF  PTS  PLUS_MINUS  VIDEO_AVAILABLE
0     22023       2544  0022300076  OCT 26, 2023  LAL vs. PHX  W   35    7   14   0.500     1     5     0.20    6    8    0.75     1     7    8    9    2    2    5   1   21          22                1
1     22023       2544  0022300061  OCT 24, 2023    LAL @ DEN  L   29   10   16   0.625     1     4     0.25    0    1    0.00     1     7    8    5    1    0    0   1   21           7                1
```

To get all data for 2023:

```
Test = playergamelog.PlayerGameLog(player_id=2544, season=SeasonAll.all).get_data_frames()[0]
Test['GAME_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(Test['GAME_DATE'], format='%b %d, %Y')
Test23 = Test[Test['GAME_DATE'].dt.year == 2023]
```

Output:

```
   SEASON_ID  Player_ID     Game_ID  GAME_DATE      MATCHUP WL  MIN  FGM  FGA  FG_PCT  FG3M  FG3A  FG3_PCT  FTM  FTA  FT_PCT  OREB  DREB  REB  AST  STL  BLK  TOV  PF  PTS  PLUS_MINUS  VIDEO_AVAILABLE
0      22023       2544  0022300076 2023-10-26  LAL vs. PHX  W   35    7   14   0.500     1     5    0.200    6    8   0.750     1     7    8    9    2    2    5   1   21          22                1
1      22023       2544  0022300061 2023-10-24    LAL @ DEN  L   29   10   16   0.625     1     4    0.250    0    1   0.000     1     7    8    5    1    0    0   1   21           7                1
2      22022       2544  0022201228 2023-04-09  LAL vs. UTA  W   33   13   25   0.520     8    14    0.571    2    2   1.000     1     5    6    6    1    1    2   0   36          20                1
3      22022       2544  0022201212 2023-04-07  LAL vs. PHX  W   29    6   19   0.316     3     7    0.429    1    2   0.500     0     6    6    6    0    0    5   1   16          11                1
4      22022       2544  0022201196 2023-04-05    LAL @ LAC  L   35   13   20   0.650     4     6    0.667    3    5   0.600     0     8    8    7    1    1    6   0   33         -10                1
5      22022       2544  0022201186 2023-04-04    LAL @ UTA  W   38   14   27   0.519     3    10    0.300    6    6   1.000     0     5    5    6    1    1    5   2   37          -7                1
6      22022       2544  0022201171 2023-04-02    LAL @ HOU  W   29    8   18   0.444     1     7    0.143    1    1   1.000     2     8   10   11    0    1    1   1   18          23                1
7      22022       2544  0022201157 2023-03-31    LAL @ MIN  W   32    7   19   0.368     1     3    0.333    3    4   0.750     1     9   10    6    1    2    3   1   18           3                1
8      22022       2544  0022201140 2023-03-29    LAL @ CHI  W   31   10   19   0.526     1     3    0.333    4    4   1.000     3     5    8    4    2    0    4   2   25          23                1
9      22022       2544  0022201114 2023-03-26  LAL vs. CHI  L   30    6   11   0.545     0     2    0.000    7    8   0.875     1     7    8    3    0    0    5   2   19           4                1
10     22022       2544  0022200913 2023-02-26    LAL @ DAL  W   37   10   23   0.435     1     6    0.167    5    7   0.714     3     5    8    3    1    1    3   4   26           0                1
11     22022       2544  0022200893 2023-02-23  LAL vs. GSW  W   26    5   20   0.250     2     6    0.333    1    2   0.500     3     6    9    8    0    0    2   2   13          22                1
12     22022       2544  0022200882 2023-02-15  LAL vs. NOP  W   29    7   14   0.500     0     5    0.000    7   10   0.700     0     6    6    6    0    1    4   1   21          14                1
13     22022       2544  0022200821 2023-02-07  LAL vs. OKC  L   34   13   20   0.650     4     6    0.667    8   10   0.800     0     7    7    3    3    0    4   3   38           8                1
14     22022       2544  0022200798 2023-02-04    LAL @ NOP  L   40   10   22   0.455     1     7    0.143    6    9   0.667     0     9    9    6    0    0    2   2   27          -5                1
15     22022       2544  0022200778 2023-02-02    LAL @ IND  W   33   11   19   0.579     2     5    0.400    2    2   1.000     2     5    7    7    0    0    3   1   26          -4                1
16     22022       2544  0022200765 2023-01-31    LAL @ NYK  W   43   11   25   0.440     2     8    0.250    4    7   0.571     1     9   10   11    1    0    5   2   28          22                1
17     22022       2544  0022200749 2023-01-28    LAL @ BOS  L   44   15   30   0.500     6    12    0.500    5    6   0.833     1     8    9    8    0    0    2   2   41           2                1
18     22022       2544  0022200729 2023-01-25  LAL vs. SAS  W   35    8   20   0.400     1     6    0.167    3    4   0.750     1     8    9   11    0    0    6   0   20           2                1
19     22022       2544  0022200719 2023-01-24  LAL vs. LAC  L   33   16   29   0.552     9    14    0.643    5    5   1.000     1     7    8    7    2    1    0   0   46         -14                1
20     22022       2544  0022200705 2023-01-22    LAL @ POR  W   36   14   24   0.583     2     7    0.286    7   10   0.700     0    11   11    4    0    2    4   2   37          17                1
21     22022       2544  0022200690 2023-01-20  LAL vs. MEM  W   37    8   21   0.381     1     5    0.200    6    7   0.857     2     7    9    6    2    2    3   4   23           9                1
22     22022       2544  0022200677 2023-01-18  LAL vs. SAC  L   37   11   25   0.440     2     9    0.222    8    9   0.889     0     8    8    9    1    1    1   0   32         -16                1
23     22022       2544  0022200664 2023-01-16  LAL vs. HOU  W   36   16   26   0.615     5    10    0.500   11   12   0.917     1     7    8    9    0    0    0   1   48          19                1
24     22022       2544  0022200655 2023-01-15  LAL vs. PHI  L   35   15   23   0.652     1     5    0.200    4    5   0.800     0     8    8   10    1    1    3   1   35          19                1
25     22022       2544  0022200630 2023-01-12  LAL vs. DAL  L   47    9   28   0.321     0     7    0.000    6   10   0.600     6    10   16    9    2    0    3   0   24          -3                1
26     22022       2544  0022200595 2023-01-07    LAL @ SAC  W   38   14   28   0.500     1     6    0.167    8    9   0.889     1     7    8    7    1    0    4   2   37          15                1
27     22022       2544  0022200590 2023-01-06  LAL vs. ATL  W   33   10   19   0.526     1     5    0.200    4    6   0.667     0     7    7   10    0    0    5   0   25          12                1
28     22022       2544  0022200551 2023-01-02    LAL @ CHA  W   40   16   26   0.615     0     5    0.000   11   15   0.733     0    11   11    6    1    0    3   1   43           9                1
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, what if I wanted data from `PlayerGameLogs`, is it possible to get it? There are more fields in this dataset.

Comment: Try `playergamelogs.PlayerGameLogs(player_id_nullable = 2544).get_data_frames()[0]`. As you can see, the latest data is for 2016.